# Show that the solution to $Ax = b$ is a critical points of $f(x)$

Tags: systems-of-equations, convex-optimization, numerical-linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, positive-definite

Given the system of linear equations (the matrix of the system is symmetric and positive definite):
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
10x + 5y = 5\\ 
5x + 3y = 4
\end{matrix}\right.$$

The solution to the system is $x = -1, y = 3$.

Now, the solution to  $Ax = b$ is a critical point of quadratic form $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^TAx - b^Tx+ c$. The critical point of this function can be found by setting gradient of this function equal to zero:
$$\nabla f = \frac{1}{2}x^TA + \frac{1}{2}Ax - b^T = \frac{1}{2}Ax + \frac{1}{2}A^Tx - b = \frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)x - b = Ax - b = 0$$
So, $Ax = b$ can be solved by finding an $x$ that minimizes $f(x)$.

Next, the quadratic function expressed with the given matrix $A$ is of the form:
$$f(x) =\begin{bmatrix}
x & y 
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
10 & 5\\ 
5 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\ 
y
\end{bmatrix} - 
\begin{bmatrix}
5 & 4
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x\\ 
y
\end{bmatrix} = 10x^2 + 10xy + 3y^2 - 5x - 4y$$

Finally, when I am minimizing the function above (in Matlab, for instance) it gives the following results:

> > fun = @(x)10*x(1)^2 + 10*x(1)*x(2) + 3*x(2)^2 - 5*x(1) - 4*x(2);
> > x0 = [-2,2];
> > x = fminsearch(fun,x0)

x =

-0.5000    1.5000
that is definetly not an answer to the system above. Where am I wrong?

Comment: You need to do your own debugging. You are missing ${1 \over 2}$.

Comment: @copper.hat you're right, I deleted my comment cause saw it right after.

Comment: @copper.ha yes, indeed when I divide $x^TAx$ by 2 the minimum become exactly the same, but why shoud I? I thought division appeared only in case of not symmetric matrices

Comment: I don't understand your question. The f in your formula above should be the same as passed to Matlab.

Comment: My question is when we build the quadratic form (function) based on matrix (positive definite, symmetric) do we need multiply main the term $x^TAx$ by 0.5 ? It seems like yes, can you please tell me where this scalar come from?

Comment: I really do not understand what you are asking. To solve $Ax=b$ where $A>0$ you note that $Ax=b$ is the unique critical point (minimiser) of $f$ above. Hence if you minimise $f$ exactly you get the solution of $Ax=b$.